# Fatal Error while sending a multipart POST request to a image upload created using Field API

Tags: entities, testing, media

While testing a site i created using "Acunetix" web vulnerability scanner, it posted a multipart request to a  image upload field created using Field API.

The test manipulated a POST statement and got an error message back.

POST (multipart) input organisation_image[und][0][height] was set to 198.

Error message found: Fatal error

I cant figure out what is happening. Any ideas how to solve this.